# XPath expression to find all elemnts that exist

Tags: java, xpath

I need help with a XPath expression that matches every elements wherever they are. This

```
for (String tag:tags) {
  StringBuffer expression = new StringBuffer("//" + tag + "/text()");}
}
```

This matched everything but now I need to apply a fix for the possible XPath Injection. So I am trying to implement this using XPathVarableResolver.

```
for (String tag:tags) {
  MapVariableResolver vr = new MapVariableResolver();
  vr.addVariable(new QName(null, "tag"), tag);
  xPath.setXPathVariableResolver(vr);
  StringBuffer expression = new StringBuffer("//$tag/text()");}
  XPathExpression expr = xPath.compile(expression.toString());
  nodeList = (NodeList) expr.evaluate(doc,XPathConstants.NODESET);
}
```

But I am getting an exception with a XPath exception.
**javax.xml.transform.TransformerException: A location step was expected following the '/' or '//' token.**

StringBuffer expression = new StringBuffer("//$tag/text()");

what would be the correct expression here?
"//$tag/text()"??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that `$tag` is stored as a XPath string variable, you can try to filter element by comparing its name as follow :

```
StringBuffer expression = new StringBuffer("//*[name()=$tag]/text()");
```

Comment: Thank you so much. This was what I was looking for.

Comment: can you explain what * is for?

Comment: also if I want to do something like this(//tag1/tag2/text()), do I need * before tag2 like this                                                                                                                  //*[name()=$tag1]/*[nam()=$tag2]/text()